# prevent descendant views to take focus from father

Tags: android, view, focus

I have a custom view which overrides `LinearLayout`, I have set `isFocusable` to `true` and the view can now gain focus, but the problem is that when any of the views in the layout is clicked, the layout loses its focus. How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIt**

I can't set those view to not focusable because they won't work anymore.

Comment: it would be useful if who downvoted this could explain what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewGroup.setDescendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setDescendantFocusability%28int%29).

Comment: it doesn't work...the views in the layout can't gain the focus anymore